# regexp to match string1 unless preceded by string2

Tags: ruby, regex, string, regex-negation

Using Ruby, how can I use a single regex to match all occurrences of 'y' in "xy y ay xy +y" that are NOT preceded by x (y, ay, +y)?
/[^x]y/ matches the preceding character too, so I need an alternative...

Comment: I was going to suggest a negative lookbehind, but it looks like you're out of luck on that score: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind. *"Finally, flavors like JavaScript, Ruby and Tcl do not support lookbehind at all, even though they do support lookahead."*

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530441/how-would-you-use-a-regular-expression-to-ignore-strings-that-contain-a-specific

Comment: If look-behind assertions are not supported, we might use this: `([^x]y")|(^y")`. 'y' might appear at the start of the string and that case is not covered by `/[^x]y/`.

Comment: FYI: Ruby 2.0.0 and up DOES support lookbehind. See http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need a zero-width negative look-behind assertion.  Try `/(?<!x)y/` which says exactly what you're looking for, i.e. find all 'y' not preceeded by 'x', but doesn't include the prior character, which is the zero-width part.

Edited to add: Apparently this is only supported from Ruby 1.9 and up.

Answer (score 3):

Negative look-behind is not supported until Ruby 1.9, but you can do something similar using scan:

```
"xy y ay xy +y".scan(/([^x])(y)/) # => [[" ", "y"], ["a", "y"], ["+", "y"]]
"xy y ay xy +y".scan(/([^x])(y)/).map {|match| match[1]}  # => ["y", "y", "y"]
```

Of course, this is much more difficult if you want to avoid much more than a single character before the `y`.  Then you'd have to do something like:

```
"abby y crabby bally +y".scan(/(.*?)(y)/).reject {|str| str[0] =~ /ab/}  # => [[" ", "y"], [" ball", "y"], [" +", "y"]]
"abby y crabby bally +y".scan(/(.*?)(y)/).reject {|str| str[0] =~ /ab/}.map {|match| match[1]}  # => ["y", "y" "y"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby unfortunately doesn't support negative lookbehind, so you'll have trouble if you need to look for more than a single character. For just one character, you can take care of this by capturing the match:

```
/[^x](y)/
```

Comment: Ah, I'm not a Ruby expert - jbourque says negative lookbehind is in newer Ruby. There's your real answer.

Comment: [^x] must match one  character.  if y occurs at the beginning of the line we should match it:  /(?:\A|^|[^x])y/

Answer (score -1):

In PCRE, you use a negative look-behind:

```
(:<!x)y
```

Not sure if this is supported by Ruby, but you can always look up.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done with negative look behind, `(?<!x)y`