# Java Read file(s) with particular pattern

Tags: java, unix, file-io, filenames

I am trying to read files from unix file system with a pattern format in a java program.

The file name pattern is like this:

```
"XYZ"+"abcd1234"+MMddyyyyHHmmss
```

For example: XYZabc123403222012101329

The middle pattern of "abcd1234" is not fixed but changes, so it will be alphanumeric and total character length of 7.

How can I read the file with such pattern? The file can contain text or serialized object.

```
String path="/tmp/somedir";

final File folder = new File("/tmp/somedir");
List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                //System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
                fileNames.add(fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }

        for(String str: fileNames) {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path+"/"+str);
        }

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thank You.

Comment: I think you want to look at making your own File filter, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list(java.io.FilenameFilter)

Comment: You have to search the directory for a file which matches your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use reguler expression for filtering files. Here is the class for doc for apache commons 
http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/RegexFileFilter.html
and here is an old question about it.
[Java regexp for file filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367862/java-regexp-for-file-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a regular expression. I'm doing the exact same thing in C# right now. I have files that come from clients that have a common prefix, a date in the middle, and a common file extension.

Assuming that the abc1234 is always seven characters long, you could use the following regular expression pattern.

XYZ.{7}\d{14}

The .{7} means that any character can appear there up to seven times. The \d{14} means that it will count up to 14 digits.

Comment: You are welcome and thank you for thanking me. A lot of people certainly do not. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [this site](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html), you'll find out how to get all the files from your directory.

After this, in the method : `accept` apply a regular expression on its parameter : `name`.

For regular expression, look toward [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).